# Want to upload a file to directory in google appengine using python

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to google appengine.
I want to upload a file to a directory instead of storing as blob.

main.py

```
import cgi 
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.template \
    import render
from os import path

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        context={}
        tmpl = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'static/html/index.html')
        self.response.out.write(render(tmpl, context))

    def post(self):
       form_data = self.request.get('file')
       file_data = form_data
       f=open('static/html/'+form_data,'w')
       f.write(file_data)
       f.close



routes=[
        (r'/', MainHandler),
        ]   
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes=routes,debug=True)
```

index.html

```
> <html>
>     <head><title>test</title></head>
>     <body>hello
>        <form id="addmovieform" action="/" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
>            <input type="file" name="file" >
>            <input type="submit" name="submit">
>        </form>
>     </body>
>         </html>
```

Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py",
>   line 1536, in **call**
>       rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py",
>   line 1530, in **call**
>       rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py",
>   line 1278, in default_dispatcher
>       return route.handler_adapter(request, response)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py",
>   line 1102, in **call**
>       return handler.dispatch()   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py",
>   line 572, in dispatch
>       return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py",
>   line 570, in dispatch
>       return method(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/saravase/test/main.py", line 33, in post
>       f=open('static/html/'+form_data,'w')   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py",
>   line 589, in **init**
>       raise IOError('invalid mode: %s' % mode) IOError: invalid mode: w

please guide me ...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There's absolutely nothing special about storing data in the filesystem - practically anything you could do by writing a file you can do with `StringIO` or the blobstore.

Answer (score 3):

From "[What is Google App Engine?](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine)"

> Applications cannot write to the file system in any of the runtime
>   environments. An application can read files, but only files uploaded
>   with the application code. The app must use the App Engine datastore,
>   memcache or other services for all data that persists between
>   requests. The Python 2.7 environment allows bytecode to be read,
>   written, and modified.

You'll need to return to using the blobstore, or try the [Google Cloud Storage API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/), depending on the needs of your application.